# Any idea how to get my query to display record correctly?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Per screenshot below, we are using dataList to display several records on a page.

The way it works currently is that a user selects a location from dropdownlist and records associated with that location are displayed.

Records include courses, instructors, dates, the capacitySeating and remainingSeatings for trainings per location.

Then on each row, there is a link that says, "Register for this training"

User clicks this link to register for that course for that location.

This stores the correct record on the db and displays the remainingSeating.

Let's assume that there are 45 Capacity seating for a particulare course for a particular location.

If user registers, the 44 will display as the remaining seats to be registered for.

The issue I am currently having though is that on the display page, the value for remainingSeating is the same for all courses.

We would like to have each course display the same capacitySeating but different remainingSeatings based on how many registered for that course.

Hope my explanation is clear.

Below is the code I am currently working with:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" 
 SelectCommand="select l.LocationId,c.courseId, c.coursename,tm.trainingMode,Isnull(t.availableSeats,30) availableSeats,d.dateid,d.trainingDates, d.trainingtime, c.CourseDescription,i.instructorName, l.location,l.seating_capacity 
                from tblLocations l
                left join tblTrainings t on l.locationId = t.LocationId
                Inner Join tblCourses c on l.locationId = c.locationId
                Inner Join tblTrainingDates d on c.dateid=d.dateid 
                Inner Join tblTrainingMode tm on c.trainingModeId = tm.trainingModeId
                Inner Join tblCourseInstructor ic on c.courseId = ic.CourseId  
                Inner Join tblInstructors i on ic.instructorId = i.instructorId" 
      FilterExpression="LocationId = '{0}'" >
<FilterParameters>
 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlLocation" Name="LocationId" 
  PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
 </FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Finally, below is the screenshop.

As you can see, once you update remainingSeat for one row, the rest of the rows show the same value. That's not what we want.

I believe the issue is with the query.

![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that  `tblTrainings` holds information about *locations* and **courses** but the apropriate join

```
left join tblTrainings t on l.locationId = t.LocationId
```

contains only locationId. It should by modified

```
left join tblTrainings t on l.locationId = t.LocationId and c.courseId = t.courseId
```